# Erasmus exchange / internship after graduation?

Tags: student-exchange

I am a European student (from a Non-EU country) and I got my BA degree last year. I am planning to go to study for masters degree in my profession, but that will be during 2018 (next year).

My question is, is it possible during this 'gap' period for me to apply for an Erasmus internship/grant/mobility somewhere? I am not currently enrolled in a University, so I wonder if there are cases like mine?